# chart resizes every time it is rendered

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts

I have a chart which is rendered in the same canvas repeatedly. The canvas is not recreated. I am using Chart.js for the rendering? I find that the chart resizes every time it is rendered. I have 2 questions.

1. Can the chart be stopped from resizing?
2. Can the canvas be cleared before the next chart is rendered?

The code I have so far:

**JS:**

```
var productsLength =  payerAccArr[index].ProductsUsed.length;
  if (productsLength > 5){
    productsLength = 5
  }

  var colorArray = ["#F7464A","#46BFBD","#FDB45C","#949FB1","#4D5360"];
  var highlightArr=["#FF5A5E","#5AD3D1","#FFC870","#A8B3C5","#616774"];
  var doughnutData=[];
  for(indexer=0;indexer<productsLength;indexer++){
    var dataObj = {
      value: payerAccArr[index].ProductsUsed[indexer].TotalCost,
      color:colorArray[indexer],
      highlight: highlightArr[indexer],
      label: payerAccArr[index].ProductsUsed[indexer].ProductCode
    };

    doughnutData.push(dataObj);
  }

     // window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
        ctx.canvas.width = 268;
        ctx.canvas.height = 259;
        window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, {responsive : true, maintainAspectRatio: false});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="canvas-holder" class='hide'>
                <span id='spend'>Month-To-Date Spend By Service</span>
                <canvas id="chart-area" style='width: 268px; height:259px;'/>
```

I apologize if I have repeated a question already asked on this forum.

Comment: have you tried changing the "maintainAspectRatio" to the value of true because the aspect ratio is related to size. hope this helps

Comment: yes. did not work. so I changed it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to answer Q #2, simply use `ctx.clearRect(0,0,<width>,<height>)`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by just removing `responsive: true` and retaining only `maintainAspectRatio: false`. My code now looks like this:

```
var productsLength =  payerAccArr[index].ProductsUsed.length;
  if (productsLength > 5){
    productsLength = 5
  }

  var colorArray = ["#F7464A","#46BFBD","#FDB45C","#949FB1","#4D5360"];
  var highlightArr=["#FF5A5E","#5AD3D1","#FFC870","#A8B3C5","#616774"];
  var doughnutData=[];
  for(indexer=0;indexer<productsLength;indexer++){
    var dataObj = {
      value: payerAccArr[index].ProductsUsed[indexer].TotalCost,
      color:colorArray[indexer],
      highlight: highlightArr[indexer],
      label: payerAccArr[index].ProductsUsed[indexer].ProductCode
    };

    doughnutData.push(dataObj);
  }

     // window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
        ctx.canvas.width = 268;
        ctx.canvas.height = 259;
        window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, {maintainAspectRatio: false});
```